# "Serial voting was reversed" while I have only one item to vote on

Tags: support, status-bydesign

On Astronomy stack exchange I have only one item that people can vote on, a question from 2016. It was upvoted once that same year and gained another upvote in 2020. How can this be the target of serial upvoting? Today I got 1 such a correction for a score of -10, meaning that it must have been a short series.

Must I imagine that someone upvoted one of my contributions on *another* stack exchange site, then looked up my profile on astronomy stack exchange and found this question that was so beautiful that it also needed an upvote and that was it, and that's not allowed? Which is found out two years later? Is SE going to be like that?

Comment: To my understanding serial upvoting can mean that someone did a lot of voting in a short time, perhaps on many posts of different users. I don't think it always has to mean that it was focused on one user's posts. We all see these messages from time to time, I guess some user's voting spree just happened to include your post for one of its votes. I'm no expert and just guessing so I won't post this as an answer. For reference, I have a lot of posts and I get a message like this roughly once a week. It's just a sign that the SE site bots are doing their job. :-)

Comment: I'm here for the same reason. I don't exactly have a lot of posts or a lot of activity. It feels like the algorithm went a little rogue, at least for small data sets like mine https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/1315/eric-j?tab=reputation

Comment: I've added the [tag:status-review] tag, so that SE staff can take a look and make sure this is expected behavior.

Comment: Related MSE post: ["Serial voting was reversed" on a community where I have only 1 post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372446/335251). As stated in Catija's comment there (referencing [this answer by animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362059/335251) to [the question it was closed as a duplicate of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362020/335251)): "The answer from animuson is identical to any answer that would be put here - it's the broader voting behavior that's problematic, not voting targeted at a specific person - we can't really explain each and every case of this happening."

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks!